# why does my table show up in one cell

Tags: html, css

My table keeps show up in one cell,  not sure what i did wrong.  anyone willing to look and let me know where i went wrong.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<title>Ironton Fire department Sponsors</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div style="width:1020px; height:1020px; float:center; background-    image:url(images/zombie_5k_TM_AP_stripped.png)">
 <div class="home">
            <img src='images/home_button.jpg' name="register"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/home_button_hover.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/home_button.jpg'" onclick="location.href='index.html'"/>
        </div>
        <div class="register">
            <img src='images/register_button.jpg' name="register"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/register_button_hover.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/register_button.jpg'" onclick="location.href='register.html'"/>
        </div>
        <div class="sponsor">
            <img src='images/sponsor_button.jpg' name="sponsor"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/sponsor_button_hover.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/sponsor_button.jpg'" onclick="location.href='sponsors.html'"/>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src='images/gallery_button.jpg' name="gallery"  onMouseOver="this.src='images/gallery_button_hover.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/gallery_button.jpg'" onclick="location.href='gallery.html'" />
        </div>
  <div class="sponsors">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="250">Seth Jackson - Edward Jones</td>
        <td align="center" width="250">Heritage Mechanical </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="250">Mike Flanagan – Iron Range Auto </td>
        <td align="center" width="250">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </div>
 <div class="sform">
 < p align="center">
    <a style="color: #D91D1F;"href="Images/ZX5K Sponsorship Agreement.pdf" target="_blank">ZX5K Sponsorship Agreement</a></p></div></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is the css that covers the class .sponsors

```
.sponsors {
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 340px;
}
```

here is the link to see what i am talking about, http://www.ifdauxzx5k.com/sponsors.html

Comment: Your table is inside the sponsors class, wich you gave a width of 150px. And your cells have a combined width of 500. I guess your problem is in there. Edit: hmm, and i also see the class is missing a  'S' in your css.

Comment: `< p align="center">` there's a needless space in front of `p`

Comment: @MaHo  He has 2 divs,   `.sponsors` and `.sponsor`. Your looking at the wrong div and he gave the wrong piece of css.  `.sponsor` is the menu button. I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table doesn't show up in one cell.
But all the cells are on top of eachother, because you have `position: absolute;` on your TD in your `main.css line 62`.

```
td{
    color: #D91D1F;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is why every `TD` is going to the left top position of the table.  Remove this line and it will behave correctly.

Comment: thank you i didn't see that i had done that i had been looking at that for quite some time now.

Comment: I have one more question with this site.  why doesn't it center to the browser?  it always sits to the top and left.